# How do you target a specific type of content?

Tags: 8, nodes, flags

I have the content type (node), article, page, recipe.

The code below can be used to flag any type of content.

How do you target a specific type of content ?

For example I only want to flag the article and recipe content type.

```
<?php

/**
 * @file
 * Holds hook implementation for the Admin Task Notify module.
 */

use Drupal\flag\FlaggingInterface;
use Drupal\Core\Entity\ContentEntityBase;
use Drupal\user\Entity\User;
use Drupal\comment\Entity\Comment;

/**
 * Implements hook_node_update().
 */
function admin_task_notify_node_update(Node $node) {

    $flag_id = 'moderate_node';
    $flag_service = \Drupal::service('flag');
    $flag = $flag_service->getFlagById($flag_id);
    $account = \Drupal\user\Entity\User::load(1);
    $flag_service->flag($flag, $node, $account);

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want your hook code to only run on specific content types, simply add a conditional

```
function admin_task_notify_node_update(Node $node) {

  if ($node->getType() == 'article' || $node->getType() == 'recipe') { // conditional
    $flag_id = 'moderate_node';
    $flag_service = \Drupal::service('flag');
    $flag = $flag_service->getFlagById($flag_id);
    $account = \Drupal\user\Entity\User::load(1);
    $flag_service->flag($flag, $node, $account);
  }

}
```

---

> I have several types of content to add, is there a shorter way to do
> it ?

Using [in_array()](https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_array_in_array.asp)

```
$allowed_c_types = ['article', 'recipe', 'some_other'];
$c_type = $node->getType();

if (in_array($c_type, $allowed_c_types)) { // conditional
```

But don't hard code, use [`$flag->getBundles()`](https://git.drupalcode.org/project/flag/-/blob/adbaab83407641dc52198e7e656ce20db03207a7/src/Entity/Flag.php#L221) to get the list as [mentioned by Shawn](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/296813/27710)

```
$allowed_c_types = $flag->getBundles();
```

Comment: Awesome it works. I have several types of content to add, is there a shorter way to do it ? for example `if $node->getType() == 'article, recipe'`

Comment: @sdfff see updated answer.

Answer (score 4):

You need to configure your `moderate_node` flag in either the UI or in configuration management.

In the flag module, a flag entity is defined by the entity type (i.e. `node`) and bundles (e.g. `article`, `page`, `recipe`) that are allowed on it. If no bundles are specified, then all bundles are allowed.

In your example code, [`$flag->getBundles()`](https://git.drupalcode.org/project/flag/-/blob/adbaab83407641dc52198e7e656ce20db03207a7/src/Entity/Flag.php#L221) method will return the bundles that are allowed (empty means all). Once set, the [`$flag_service->flag`](https://git.drupalcode.org/project/flag/-/blob/adbaab83407641dc52198e7e656ce20db03207a7/src/FlagService.php#L234) method will kickback exceptions if you try to flag bundles that do not apply to that flag. You'll need to adjust the code accordingly to handle those scenarios.

Comment: thank you for the explanations